# Threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote [this small project](https://github.com/yasar11732/HttpStatusCodes) to practice threading in Java. At first, I planned to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186336/what-type-of-queue-to-use-to-distribute-jobs-between-worker-threads). But later, someone pointed me to [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Then, I found [this tutorial](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/) and followed it through. Here is my code;

```
/*
 * HttpStatusCodes
 * 
 * First version
 *
 * 2013-08-12
 * 
 * This code is copyrighted under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported
 * Copyright (c) Yaşar Arabacı http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en
 */
package com.github.HttpStatusCodes;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * A java class to fetch Http status of multiple urls in parallel.
 * The HttpStatusCodes class aims to provide an easy way to get HTTP Status
 * codes from a list of urls.
 *
 * @author Yaşar Arabacı <yasar11732@gmail.com>
 */
public class HttpStatusCodes {

    private BufferedReader input;
    private int numThreads;

    /**
     * When invoked from command line, HttpStatusCodes will read urls from the
     * files whose names were passed in arguements and print results to
     * standart output.
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            HttpStatusCodes app;
            try {
                app = new HttpStatusCodes(new FileReader(new File(arg)), 16);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File doesn't exist: " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
            HashMap<String, String> results = app.get();
            for (String key : results.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key + " " + results.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Container for pairs of urls and statuses.
     */
    private class UrlAndCode {

        public String url;
        public String statusCode;

        public UrlAndCode(String url, String statusCode) {
            this.url = url;
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class gets executed in a seperate Thread to
     * get status of a single url
     */
    private class getStatus implements Callable<UrlAndCode> {

        private String location;
        private int timeout;

        public getStatus(String location, int timeout) {
            this.location = location;
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        @Override
        public UrlAndCode call() {
            URL url;
            // to fix Malformed urls
            if (!location.startsWith("http")) {
                location = "http://" + location;
            }

            // url can still be malformed
            try {
                url = new URL(location);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                return new UrlAndCode(location, e.getMessage());
            }

            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            Integer statusCode;
            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                con.setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000);
                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                statusCode = new Integer(con.getResponseCode());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /*
                 * Exception will be returned along with url, otherwise we can't
                 * know which Exception on which url. Otherwise, it will be hard to
                 * track Exceptions.
                 */
                return new UrlAndCode(location, e.getClass() + ":" + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return new UrlAndCode(location, statusCode.toString());
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param r Urls will be read from this Reader line by line
     * @param i number of threads to use
     */
    public HttpStatusCodes(Reader r, int i) {
        input = new BufferedReader(r);
        numThreads = i;
    }

    /**
     * see {@link #HttpStatusCodes(Reader,int) HttpStatusCodes}. Timeout will
     * default to 4 seconds.
     */
    public HttpStatusCodes(Reader r) {
        this(r, 4);
    }

    /** 
     * calls {@link #get(int) get} with default timeout of 2 seconds.
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> get() {
        return get(2);
    }

    /**
     * When this method is invoked, urls will be distributed among worker threads
     * to be connected. After all urls have been tried, this method will return.
     * @param timeout How many seconds to wait before getting a response from connection.
     * @return A HashMap of <String,String> keys hold urls, values hold status codes or error messages.
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> get(int timeout) {
        HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        CompletionService<UrlAndCode> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);
        String line;
        int numWorks = 0;

        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                pool.submit(new getStatus(line, timeout));
                numWorks++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HttpStatusCodes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            threadPool.shutdown();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                /*
                 * Closing the input stream is not critical for us, will log
                 * and continue
                 */
                Logger.getLogger(HttpStatusCodes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }

        // Uncomment for debugging.
        //System.out.println(numWorks + " jobs added.");

        while (numWorks > 0) {
            UrlAndCode result;
            try {
                result = pool.take().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(HttpStatusCodes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                threadPool.shutdown();
                return null;
            }
            results.put(result.url, result.statusCode);
            numWorks--;
            // Uncomment for debugging
            // System.out.println(numWorks + " jobs remaining.");
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        return results;
    }
}
```

You can also [find the codes here](https://raw.github.com/yasar11732/HttpStatusCodes/master/src/com/github/HttpStatusCodes/HttpStatusCodes.java). I am looking for a general review.

Comment: I'll suggest you to use the interface `Map`instead of the implementation `HashMap`. More information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered

Answer (score 3):

I'll talk about the code in general, not about the functionality.

---

```
package com.github.HttpStatusCodes;
```

Package names are used to identify the associated developer with the package. The problem here is that, unless you work for GitHub and write this under their umbrella, you should not use `com.github` for your packages even if they're hosted GitHub. This might lead to the wrong assumption that it is source code released by/from GitHub Inc..

If you do not have a domain, please use your e-mail address like this:

```
package com.gmail.yasar.HttpStatusCodes
```

Or if you don't even want this, at least add your GitHub name to the package:

```
package com.github.yasar.HttpStatusCodes
```

---

```
package com.github.HttpStatusCodes;
...
public class HttpStatusCodes {
```

That's not a good way to name packages and classes. They should not have identical names, and the class name makes it sound like it's an Enum. A better naming would be something like (but still not perfect):

```
package com.github.yasar.HttpTools;
...
public class HttpStatusChecker {
```

---

```
private class getStatus implements Callable<UrlAndCode> {
```

Classes are normally UpperCamelCase...though, seems like a Typo.

---

```
public HashMap<String, String> get(int timeout) {
```

Get what? `get` is not a good name for a function. `getStatusCodes()`, `getWebsiteStatus()`, `checkWebsites()`, `doWebsiteChecking()`, `runCheck()` or something else would be a better name for this function. You should be able to derive from the name of the function it's...well, function.

---

```
public HttpStatusCodes(Reader r, int i) {
```

Quick! What is `i`?!

Fortunately, we live in a time were length of variable names do not matter, please use descriptive, even if longer, names.

```
public HttpStatusCodes(Reader reader, int numberOfThreads) {
```

If that collides with private variables, you can use `this`:

```
public HttpStatusCodes(Reader reader, int numberOfThreads) {
    this.reader = reader;
    this.numberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
}
```

---

Also consider separating the Main-Method from this class.

---

```
public HashMap<String, String> get(int timeout) {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();
```

You should always use the lowest common denominator for Objects, meaning always use the underlaying interface unless not possible.

```
public Map<String, String> get(int timeout) {
    Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();
```

That easies use of your methods and makes them more generic and flexible.

---

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
Integer statusCode;
try {
    // SNIP
    statusCode = new Integer(con.getResponseCode());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // SNIP
} finally {
    if (con != null) {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
return new UrlAndCode(location, statusCode.toString());
```

You're saving a value and return it later for no reason. `finally` will be executed even if you return out of the block and is guaranteed to always run except if you call `System.exit(0)` or something really bad happens (cleaning crew unplugging or hitting the PC).

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
    // SNIP
    return new UrlAndCode(location, con.getResponseCode().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // SNIP
} finally {
    if (con != null) {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

---

```
private class UrlAndCode {

    public String url;
    public String statusCode;

    public UrlAndCode(String url, String statusCode) {
```

HTTP Status codes are *always* integers. They're always handled as integers, so consider also keeping them as integers.

```
private class UrlAndCode {

    public String url;
    public int statusCode;

    public UrlAndCode(String url, int statusCode) {
```

I just saw that you're also using it to store error messages, in that case you should either introduce a field to the error, or rename the variable.

```
public String status;
```

Comment: If you want, you could add my comment to your answer, I think it could go well with your answer.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: Will do, thanks. I also just notice a few other things.